# A reasoning question demanding some intuition.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

This question is inclined towards logical reasoning rather than pure mathematics but I resorted to ask it here as I don't know any other site that can possible help as much as this one.

$200$ customers of a company XYZ Inc. were surveyed. The $200$ customers reported that on the customer care services they got at least one and at most six responses among $R_1,R_2, \ldots ,R_6$.

Below is the information regarding the number of customers getting a particular response.

$$\begin{array}{c} 
 & \text{Number of customers} \\ \hline
\text{$R_1$} & 160  \\ \hline
\text{$R_2$} & 160 \\ \hline
\text{$R_3$} &  160\\ \hline
\text{$R_4$} & 160 \\ \hline
\text{$R_5$} & 120 \\ \hline
\text{$R_6$} &  200\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

The questions demands that we find the maximum number of customers of XYZ Inc. whose inquiries resulted in at least five of the six responses.

I tried to solve this question by making overlapping lines on a line segment of 200 units (representing $200$ customers), and thus got $160$ as the answer however the answer key says that the answer should be $190$. Though $190$ seems not at all intuitive yet it the official answer (and we can safely assume that the answer key is right). Can anybody help me find a concrete way through which such a problem can be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $960$ results in total, which have to be split between $200$ respondents, but all gave the last response, so we are looking at $760$ over five questions and we want to know the number of people who gave at least four answers.

You want to find the maximum who gave four of these responses (not the minimum), so you are looking at $\frac {760}4=190$ as a possible maximum, if you can realise this as a possibility. There is no "waste" here and you need to incorporate the $120$ from option $5$ symmetrically to leave the same number of residual replies for the first four options and for the people who did not choose fifth. You need no-one to have chosen all six and no-one to have chosen fewer than five.

You can do this with

$30$ choosing $1,2,3,5,6$

$30$ choosing $1,2,4,5,6$

$30$ choosing $1,3,4,5,6$

$30$ choosing $2,3,4,5,6$

$70$ choosing $1,2,3,4,6$

You should check this against your method, which may work with some careful adaptation. It was easy to exploit the symmetry here, and that might not always be the case.